# if statement in script file does not return output

Tags: bash, unix

```
read code
read answer

if [[ $answer" = B && "$code" = grep $code filename ]]

then echo blue

else :

fi
done
```

Hello, if someone can help me understand why I am not receiving an output I would appreciate it. I am supposed to have two conditions in my if statement, so if the user gives a B and the file contains the "code" then it will echo blue

```
if [ $answer" = B && "$code" = '6314' ]
then echo blue

else :

fi
done
```

...

I do get an answer

Comment: the `:` is almost certainly an indication of you wanting to do something differently here – if you don't want to do anything if the condition is false, simply omit the `else` clause.

Comment: You need to write `"$(grep "$code" filename)"` to substitute the result of `grep`.

Comment: Looks like there is an open quote, shouldn't it be ``"$answer"`` instead?

Comment: the else will show .... echo enter only B or R

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting to try this:

```
if [[ "$answer" == B && "$code" == "$(grep $code filename)" ]]; then 
  echo blue
else
  echo red
fi
```

Or:

```
if [[ "$answer" == B && "$code" == '6314' ]]; then 
  echo blue
else 
  echo red
fi
```

Comment: what if i want to say code not in file? would it be !== or !=

Comment: It will be `!=` suggesting this article: https://devhints.io/bash

Comment: so i do have more to the program... I want it to say if answer is b and code is in data then echo "Blue" .... 2. elif answer is r and code is data echo "red" 3. elif answer is b and the code is NOT in data echo "not a thing" 4. elif answer is r and the code is not in data echo " not a thing" ..... else echo only r or b

Comment: Suggesting this article: https://linuxhandbook.com/if-else-bash/

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$answer" = "B" ] && [ "`grep \"$code\" filename`" = "$code" ]; then
  echo code blue
else
  echo code red
fi
```